# mailchimp show api error

Tags: php, forms, mailchimp

I'm writing a contact form in php, at the bottom of which is a checkbox that says "add me to the newsletter" (i.e. mailchimp).

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
<?php

use Uniform\Form;

return function ($site, $pages, $page)
{
  $form = new Form([
    'email_address' => [
      'rules' => ['required', 'email'],
      'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
    ],
  ]);

  if (r::is('POST')) {
    $form->webhookAction([
      'url' => 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXX/members/',
      'json' => true,
      'params' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'data' => ['status' => 'pending'],
        'headers' => ['Authorization: apikey YYYY'],
      ],
    ]);
  }

  return compact('form');
};
```

(originally taken from https://kirby-uniform.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/webhook/)

For some reason, the email address doesn't get added to my list.

Is there a way to print the API's response? I'd like to debug the problem; it may very well just be that my email address is banned due to too many attempts ...

Comment: Not familiar with what library you are using there, but I would assume that $form->webhookAction has some kind of return value? What does the documentation for this lib say about this?